# Error 1 The modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item

Tags: c#, .net, interface, abstract

I'm trying to build my C# project, I get the error:

```
The modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item
```

In the following Interface:

```
namespace program.Drawing.Fields
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public interface IFieldHolder
    {
        abstract event FieldChangedEventHandler FieldChanged;

        void AddField(Field field);
        Field GetField(FieldType fieldType);
        List<Field> GetFields();
        bool HasField(FieldType fieldType);
        void RemoveField(Field field);
        void SetFieldValue(FieldType fieldType, object value);
    }
}
```

The item:
    FieldChanged;

```
The modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item
```

Comment: @Matthew: His interface isn't defining any fields...

Comment: And what is the question? Removing `abstract` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces by definition are abstract in that implementing classes must fulfil them. You cannot use the abstract keyword inside them. (Same goes for scoping)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here but you may find the following information helpful:

"Interfaces and interface members are abstract; interfaces do not provide a default implementation."

[Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

That is to say, members of an Interface are implicitly abstract.